# Python-Selenium-Chrome: how to get access to the whole document property

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium

I need to get the whole html code of a page which uses JavaScript. I use Selenium module with Chrome and see different 'find' methods, but didn't find some sort of ".document" property (like ie.document in VBA). Is there some possibility to get the whole result code (after JS execution) in string format for example?

Comment: Try `driver.page_source` to scrap all html code..

Comment: this method returns html code without java script executing (